# Get RuntimeWarning when running Jupyter notebook and never connects to Kernel

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a fresh install of python 3.7.2 and pip installed jupyter 4.4.0 in a fresh venv on Windows 7.0 professional.
I started a Jupyter notebook and my notebook never connects to the kernel.
On the command prompt, I see this error:

```
[I 17:41:11.959 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98
[I 17:41:14.307 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98
<full path masked>...\py372venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py:284: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'WebSocketHandler.get' was never awaited
  super(AuthenticatedZMQStreamHandler, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
[W 17:41:15.404 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98:3b9a037fced84ccc891192e2f387bae0
[W 17:41:37.415 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98:3b9a037fced84ccc891192e2f387bae0
[W 17:42:01.421 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98:3b9a037fced84ccc891192e2f387bae0
[W 17:42:29.468 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98:3b9a037fced84ccc891192e2f387bae0
[W 17:43:05.489 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 35b03148-7d3e-48cb-a270-ebe959012d98:3b9a037fced84ccc891192e2f387bae0
```

These replacing stale connection messages continue.
What could be the issue? I am new to Jupyter and a bit less new to Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to downgrade tornado version (`pip install 'tornado<6'`), as described there: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4437#issuecomment-468758440

For me, downgrading from 6.0.1 to 5.1.1 solved the issue with jupyter not connecting to kernel.

Comment: Thanks Grigory. That worked. In fact I tried downgrading to 5.0.0 as well and that worked too. I am going to mark this as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

install 5.1.1 version and try.

```
pip.exe" show tornado
Name: tornado
**Version: 5.1.1**
Summary: Tornado is a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library, originally developed at FriendFeed.
Home-page: http://www.tornadoweb.org/
Author: Facebook
Author-email: python-tornado@googlegroups.com
License: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Location: c:\users\<userid>\path\to\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: jupyterhub, notebook, jupyter-client, ipykernel, distributed, bokeh, anaconda-project
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.